# (iphone) UIViewController having UITableViewController as member to make tableView as it's subview?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, tableview

I want a viewController's view have a tableView as its subview.

Since I need to override some methods of tableViewController such as

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

, I had my viewController to possess (custom)TableViewController instead of tableView.

Then, I do something like,

```
UIView* holderView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview holderView]; //self is viewController
[holderView addSubview: tableViewController.view];
.. change tableViewController.view.backgroundColor so on..
```

then, tableView magically(?) fills the holderView and works fine.

But I sense this is rather irregular and wonder what's the best practice to have a customized table view as subview?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did (and is done more commonly I believe), is to make the viewController the table's delegate as well. That means that controller has functions like viewDidLoad, but it also needs the numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath, etcetera.. 
When setting the delegate of the table to the viewController (self), it means the table will look for the information required to build the table on that delegate. The delegate contains those table-functions.

EDIT: I just saw the 'custom' prefix on your table. In that case, I'd still use my described method but use CustomCells instead.

Comment: ah, thanks, then I will just need to have tableView created and set delegate of the tableView to viewController. i won't need to access tableViewController.view.. am i getting it right? , delegate and  datasource will be set through tableView?

Comment: @Eugene Thats correct, you don't need to access the view. You need to access your viewController.h, though. Change the `@interface viewController:UIViewController {` to `@interface viewController:UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegage> {`. After this, XCode (this is your SDK?) knows the required methods and displays an error if you don't.